# MySQL coalesce two nullable BITs gives result =48

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce, mysql-8.0

I have a query with two nullable bit flag columns and I would like to coalesce those in result set into single flag:

```
COALESCE(flagA, flagB) as FlagAB
```

however for column values `null, false` the result is `48` rather than `false` which is rather unexpected. Playground example (also on [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d172d9ff8d1f3fffff8df85fbf03ad8d)):

```
create table Flags (flagA bit null, flagB bit null);
insert into Flags  (flagA, flagB) values (null, false);

select *, COALESCE(flagA, flagB) as FlagAB from Flags;
```

output:

```
| FlagA | FlagB | FlagAB |
--------------------------
| null  | 0     | 48     |
```

What is going on and how can I fix the query so that it returns correctly coalesced flag?

Comment: COALESCE uses only standard datatypes - some INT in your case. CAST the output to BINARY(1) explicitly.

Comment: Why did you choose bit for the data type of a flag column? Why not boolean? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6973200972855c1a965f653db8a670ba

Comment: @Akina thanks, that almost answers my question. However is there an option to keep original type bit(1) in result? According to IDE binary results in a varbinary rather than  bit(1). The ORM also gets confused and interpret it as 30. I have tried casting it to bit but that is a syntax error.

Comment: @forpas historic reasons, inherited the database - just adding a new query.